# How to do a single value prediction in NLP

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

My dataset was restaurants review with two columns review and liked.
Based on the review it shows if they liked the restaurant or not

I cleaned up the data in NLP as the first step.Then as second step used bag of words model as below.

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

cv = CountVectorizer(max_features = 1500)

X = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()

y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values
```

This above gave X as 1500 columns with 0 and 1 with 1000 rows according to my dataset.

I predicted  as below

```py
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

So now I have review as "Food was good",how do I predict if they like it or not.A single value to predict.

Please can you help me out.Please let me know if additional information is required.

Thanks

Comment: read about bag of words model for sentiment analysis (postive and negative words). 

FYI, this forum is to post code samples for debugging. you may have to look at other stack exchange forums like  https://datascience.stackexchange.com to get better recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to apply `cv.transform` first just like so:

```py
>>> test = ['Food was good']
>>> test_vec = cv.transform(test)
>>> classifier.predict(test_vec)
# returns predicted class
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out.I tried this.This worked for me.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

For training and testing here is simple example:

Training:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
text = ["This is good place","Hyatt is awesome hotel"]

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(text)
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

pd.DataFrame(X_train_tfidf.todense(), columns = count_vect.get_feature_names())
# Now apply any classification u want to on top of this data-set
```

Now Testing:

Note: use the same transformation as done in training:

```py
new = ["I like the ambiance of this hotel "]

pd.DataFrame(tfidf_transformer.transform(count_vect.transform(new)).todense(), 
             columns = count_vect.get_feature_names())
```

Apply model.predict on top of this now.

Comment: There is no need to use `tfidfTransformer`

Answer (score 0):

you can also use sklearn pipeline.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
model_pipeline = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()), ('model', classifier())]) #call the Model which you want to use

model_pipeline.fit_transform(x,y) # here x is your text data, and y is going to be your target
model_pipeline.predict(['Food was good"'])  # predict your new sentence
```